# Trouble With Static UICulture Setting and Implicit Localization

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, localization, culture

I’m playing with implicit localization on my Win7 box via VS2010 and something doesn’t quite seem right.   I have a trivial page where I set the resourceKey of my GO Button to “bnGO”:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1" uiculture="es" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test Implicit Localization</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="bnGO" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="bnGO" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have both testForm.aspx.resx and testForm.es.aspx.resx files that set the value of bnGO.Text appropriately:

[image: English Local Resources File]
[image: Spanish Local Resources File]

When I run the application, the GO Button displays the "Go Forth!" text defined in the default  testForm.aspx.resx even though testForm.aspx has uiculture set to “es” (which I *think* is Spanish).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the file should be:

```
testForm.aspx.es.resx
```

---

Not

```
testForm.es.aspx.resx
```